# How to navigate through SharePoint list items in Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with an Infopath form associated with it. Once we opened up an item from the list, I need to have a way to navigate through next and previous items using next and previous buttons on the Infopath form. So I don't need to close a item and go to the list view again to open up the next item.

I tried to do this with a secondary data connection to load data to the existing form. It was successful. But the problem is when we try to edit and save the item. it updates the original item where we opened up the Infopath form. Is there any way to achieve this functionality. Any suggestions would be mostly welcome. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Doing this .. you must navigate it to The Whole URL..

so Do this ..

1. Get ID of the current Item.
2. create a Rule or you can use Code for button click event. .. on Button Next Click  user clicks the button it will Redirect the page to other URL along with the Current ID + 1 ....
3. Same process for the Previous button ..

Answer (score 0):

Get the Name/FileName of the item that you are editing, then create a submit data connection that "overwrites" that filename. In this case, you won't be updating the original item but the other items.